# calling .mexw64 in Octave GNU

Tags: matlab, octave, mex

I tried to copy/paste some Matlab code into Octave, but I got error message pointing to a mexw64 file which I understood a wrapped c++ file.
I did not find too much info how to solve compatibility between the above mentioned file type and octave. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Alas, the question is incredibly vague and devoid of details, so the only real help I can provide is to point out the [manual section about mex files in octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Mex_002dFiles.html#Mex_002dFiles). Good luck!

Comment: It doesnt necesarily need to work. Id sugges you recompile the source

Comment: Hi, did you figureout how to solve this problem? I encountered the same problem: I have a .mexw64 files that I am trying to call from Octave GNU

Comment: @LouisKuang when I created the mex file myself it worked but with the particular one, it did not. I went through this example...https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Getting-Started-with-Mex_002dFiles.html#Getting-Started-with-Mex_002dFiles